# Induction differential proof

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, induction

So I was doing an induction proof that contained a differential. Now I got through most of it but lastly in order to complete the proof I needed to prove

$$\frac{d^k  }{dx^k}x^k=k!$$
Now I don't need to do this via induction or anything it's just that inside the actual induction proof this statement was there and in order to prove the $(k+1)$-th term I need to show this.

I can see how this would happen:

$\frac{d  }{dx}x^k = k(x^{k-1})$

$\frac{d^2  }{dx^2}x^k  = k(k-1)x^{k-2}$
..
...
..
Until eventually I would get

$k\cdot (k-1)\cdot (k-2)\cdot (k-3)\cdot ... \cdot x^{k-k}$

Which in turn would be $k!$

However is there any better way of showing this, like a more formal proof or better strucutred one ?

Comment: Its not hard to prove it with induction.

Comment: What you wrote looks good enough if only it was typeset in MathJax.

Comment: Besides proving $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^k) = k!$ by induction on $k$, you could also formalize your argument directly: prove by induction on $n$ that whenever $1 \le n \le k$, then $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^k) = \frac{k!}{(k-n)!} x^{k-n}$.

Comment: A tutorial for typing mathematics in MathJax can be found here, by the way: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that you don't need to do this via induction, but it's a good way of doing it. What I mean by this is that you can prove by induction on $k$ that $\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dx^k}x^n=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)x^{n-k}$, where $n\geqslant k$. If $k=1$, this is just the assertion that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x=1$. Suppose that it is true for some $k$. Then\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d^{k+1}}{\mathrm dx^{k+1}}x^n&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dx^k}x^n\right)\\&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)x^{n-k}\right)\\&=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)(n-k)x^{n-k-1}\end{align}

Comment: You go exactly the opposite way with your induction than I do, José :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another way : suppose $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n) = n!$ for some $n\in\mathbf N$. Then :
$$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(x^{n+1}) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x^{n+1})\right) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}((n+1)x^n) = (n+1)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n) = (n+1)n! = (n+1)!$$
There you have to know the first derivative of $x^n$ for any $n$, which can be proved... by induction, knowing the derivative of a product and the derivative of $x$ and $1$ :-)